# Python Scapy nfqueue

Tags: python, linux, iptables, scapy

Im writing python code to interact with iptables nfqueue on linux systems. I am able to retrieve the queue packets and modify them as i wish however i am having trouble accepting them through the queue.

```
            payload.set_verdict_modified(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT, str(p), len(p))
```

That is the line that to my understanding will allow it through the queue. p is the new packet that i have created and payload is the orginal queue packet.

There really isnt too much documentation on this so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

This is how i create the packet

```
def queue_callback(i, payload)

    data = payload.get_data()
    packet = IP(data)
```

This is where i create the packet. I do a little bit of packet manipulation and this is where i return it

```
    packet[TCP].payload = after;

    return packet;
```

After i return the packet i try to update the nfqueue in iptables using the previous command

```
            p = modify(packet)
            print p[TCP].payload
            payload.set_verdict_modified(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT, str(p), len(p))
```

The modify function is where i create a new packet and return it.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the problem, as well as the code where you create `p`?

Comment: I updated the post. Thanks for the help btw, there really is not documentation for this online. I've looked quite a bit. The problem is that the packet is getting modified how i want. The tcp payload is correct however i dont know how to like re accept the new packet. The packet is queue in the iptables firewall and then i want to update the packet and then allow it through. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where do you modify the packet. Normally your packet manipulation should be in the call back function:

```
def cb(payload):
    data = payload.get_data()
    p = IP(data)
    #Here you can manipulate the packet and modify it as you want
    p[IP].src = "10.2.0.2" #change the src address for exemple

    payload.set_verdict_modified(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT, str(p), len(p))
```

and then you call the call back function after creating the queue:

```
    q.set_callback(cb)
    q = nfqueue.queue()
    q.open()
    q.create_queue(0) #Same queue number of the iptables rule
```

Comment: Have you managed to modify the payload¿? Because I can't, if I do it I receive no answer. Do I need to change any other TCP/IP Header to accomplish it¿?

Comment: I think if you change the payload, you should recalculate the checksum. This can be done by removing the old checksum using `no p.checksum` then scapy will recalculate the new checksum automatically.